# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have Permission Roles that i want to delete when i click on them so i did a route that takes role id and permission id

```
Route::post('management/role-permission/{role_id}/{permission_id}', 'RolePermissionsController@Delete');
```

And i get this route from link from my html:

```
 @foreach($data as $dat)
                <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                    <form  action="/management/role-permission/{{$role->id}}/{{$dat->id}}" method="POST">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                        <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"  class="btn turquoiseButton btn-margin full-width"><i class='fa fa-close close-btn'></i> {{$dat->name}} </button>
                    </form>
                </div>

@endforeach
```

And the route goes to this controller :

```
 public function Delete( $role_id ,$permission_id)
{
    $role_permission=DB::table('permission_role')
        ->where('role_id' ,$role_id)
        ->where('permission_id' ,$permission_id)
        ->delete();
    return Redirect::to('/management/role-permission/'.$role_id . '/list');
}
```

But i keep getting this error for no reason

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: You have a POST (in form tag) method and a DELETE (as a form field) but you route is "post", remove the "delete" field and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Route::post('management/role-permission/{role_id}/{permission_id}', 'RolePermissionsController@Delete');
```

To

```
Route::delete('management/role-permission/{role_id}/{permission_id}', 'RolePermissionsController@Delete');
```